# What happens if I play Quagmire/Bear Trap on myself on AR 7?

Tags: twilight-struggle

**Quagmire*** says the following:

> On next action round, US player must discard an Operations card worth 2 or more *and* roll 1-4 to cancel this event. Repeat each US player Action round until successful or no appropriate cards remain. If out of appropriate cards the US player may only play scoring cards until the next turn.

I know this can be used on AR 6 to discard an undesirable card with sufficient Ops on turn 7.  But what happens if you play it on turn 7?

It says "on next action round" at the beginning. Does that mean AR 1 on the next turn? Or does it go away at the end of the turn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quagmire/Bear Trap don't go away at the end of the turn !

From the FAQ:

> ## 46
>
> Q. Does a Beartrap or Quagmire end when the turn ends or will it continue into the next
> turn?
>
> A. The end of a turn will not end a Beartrap or Quagmire. Only the required die roll will
> do so. Remember that neither card affects headline phase.

So, if you play it in AR7 you will not play AR1 of the next turn (except you played it in TURN10), you just discard a card and try your luck.